# How do I secure Elmah on ASP.Net MVC 4 with Windows Integrated Security : Elmah ignores my settings

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, security, elmah

I've added elmah to an asp.net mvc 4 application.
Logging is working and now I am trying to configure security but elmah is not picking up the settings and the logs remain visible by all users.

This is an intranet app and as such we are using windows integrated secuirty. I am trying to restrict access so that only members of the domain\log_readers ad group can read the logs.

I've read the setup guide here: http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages and I've also read several posts on SO and other formums which has led me to add the roleManager and WindowsRoleProvider configuration, all to no avail.

Here are the elmah parts of my web.config:

```
<elmah>
<!--
    See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
    more information on remote access and securing ELMAH.
-->
<security allowRemoteAccess="true" />
<errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/Logs" />  
</elmah>
<location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows" />

  <roleManager defaultProvider="WindowsProvider"
      enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false">
    <providers>
      <add
        name="WindowsProvider"
        type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
    </providers>
  </roleManager>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
  </httpHandlers>
  <!-- 
    See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
    more information on using ASP.NET authorization securing ELMAH.
  -->
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="domain\log_readers"/>
    <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>

</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
</location>
```

I have also tried a complete lock down by setting my autorisation config to deny everyone

```
<authorization>
<deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

and also

```
<authorization>
<deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

The logs remain open to everyone.

I suspect the problem may be with the location. I've made no changes to the elmah location. It is accessed from default location (http://server/myapp/elmah)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you use Elmah.Mvc they have quite fine grained security settings. You can easily secure the elmah page to only be available to logged in users in the Admin group for instance.

Elmah.Mvc supports the following items in `<appSettings>`

```
<appSettings>
    <!-- ELMAH configuration. Admin page only available for logged in users in 
         the Admin role. -->
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="true" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="Admin" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
</appSettings>
```

The keys of interest are `elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication` which switches on the user needing to be logged in. And `elmah.mvc.allowedRoles` which specifies which role the user must be in.

You can install Elmah.Mvc from nuget.

Comment: I have elmah.mvc installed I'll give that a try.  Are those settings in addition or instead of the ones I have already set up

Comment: If you installed Elmah.Mvc through nuget it should have added the above to your web.config automatically. The above settings are instead of the ones you've already configured.

Comment: If you are using windows auth, you need to include the domain (case sensitive) for `elmah.mvc.allowedUsers` to work properly. Prior versions of elmah didn't require the domain.

Answer (score 3):

The above answer worked great, once I found out how to determine the Role when using Windows Authentication:

Open a command window and enter the following command:

```
cmd /k net user <user> /Domain
```

For `<user>`, substitute your user name. The command will list the groups you belong to.

The instructions came from "How to Create an Intranet Site Using ASP.NET MVC" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322(VS.98).aspx